# RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:2

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch

I have 4 GPUs (0,1,2,3) and I want to run one Jupyter notebook on GPU 2 and another one on GPU 0. Thus, after executing,

```
 export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3
```

for the GPU 2 notebook I do,

```
device = torch.device( f'cuda:{2}' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
device, torch.cuda.device_count(), torch.cuda.is_available(), torch.cuda.current_device(), torch.cuda.get_device_properties(1)
```

and after creating a new model or loading one,

```
model = nn.DataParallel( model, device_ids = [ 0, 1, 2, 3])
model = model.to( device)
```

Then, when I start training the model, I get,

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-849ffcb53e16> in <module>
 46             with torch.set_grad_enabled( phase == 'train'):
 47                 # [N, Nclass, H, W]
 ---> 48                 prediction = model(X)
 49                 # print( prediction.shape, y.shape)
 50                 loss_matrix = criterion( prediction, y)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
492         else:
--> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
144                 raise RuntimeError("module must have its parameters and buffers "
145                                    "on device {} (device_ids[0]) but found one of "
--> 146                                    "them on device: {}".format(self.src_device_obj, t.device))
147 
148         inputs, kwargs = self.scatter(inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids)

RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:0 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:2
```

Comment: `DataParallel` requires every input tensor be provided on the first device in its `device_ids` list. It basically uses that device as a staging area before scattering to other gpus and it's the device where final outputs are gathered before returning from forward. I think `device_ids = [2, 0, 1, 3]` would work if you want device 2 to be your main device though I haven't tested this.

Comment: I will agree with you, because setting device_ids = [2] it works. I wish DataParallel documentation to be better on this. I will have this comment as an answer later today. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`DataParallel` requires every input tensor be provided on the **first device in its `device_ids` list**.

It basically uses that device as a staging area before scattering to the other GPUs and it's the device where final outputs are gathered before returning from forward. If you want device 2 to be the primary device then you just need to put it at the front of the list as follows

```
model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids = [2, 0, 1, 3])
model.to(f'cuda:{model.device_ids[0]}')
```

After which all tensors provided to model should be on the first device as well.

```
x = ... # input tensor
x = x.to(f'cuda:{model.device_ids[0]}')
y = model(x)
```

Comment: Won't doing `model.to(f'cuda:{model.device_ids[0]}')` use only GPU 2 and defeat the purpose of model parallel?

Comment: And I still get `RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0`

Comment: @jadog Figured out, I hadn't reinitialized the model for different parameters. Thanks.

Comment: Does not work for me. If I run `model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[5])` and `model.to(f'cuda:{model.device_ids[0]}')`, I get: `RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:5 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0`. The memory entry on cuda:0 is there, that is not wrong, but it happens while i run this, before, memory is at 0. I cleaned the memory (`!kill -9 123456`) and with this, restarted the kernel. And I tried `device = torch.device('cuda:5')` and `model.to(device)`.

Comment: I made a check: I set the environment variable to `[5]` so that I would have just one GPU, both with `!export...` and with `%set_env`, then built the model, and the memory was again spread over all GPU:s: `RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:5 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0`. Thus, at the very first step when i assign the GPU, it already touches GPU 0 (or sometimes GPU 1 even though I only have GPU 5 as an input. I saw that `!export...` does not change `%env`, only `%env_set`. I might be on a wrong user/virtual environment?

Comment: I found out that it does not matter for my setup whether I have set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` or not. I set it to `[6]`, ran the same as above again (but choosing GPU 5 for the DataParallel class), and the outcome was the same: `RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:5 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0`. The env must likely be set before launching Jupyter Notebook and not just after memory cleaning/kernel restart, see [Forgot to set it before...](https://ericmjl.github.io/blog/2021/5/14/set-environment-variables-inside-a-jupyter-notebook/).

Comment: I opened a question at [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters ... on device cuda:6 (device_ids\[0\]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556).

Answer (score 0):

this error happened when using the torch, model  and data both are not on cuda:

try some code like this to model and data set on cuda

```
model = model.toDevice('cuda')
images = images.toDevice('cuda')
```

Comment: images
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'toDevice'

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataParallel' object has no attribute 'toDevice'`

Comment: Taken from another remark: "`device='cuda'` is synonymous with `device='cuda:0'` which is the default primary device for `DataParallel`". Thus, change "cuda" to the chosen GPU that where want to save the parameters and buffers.

Answer (score 0):

```
model = nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids = [ 0, 1, 2, 3]).cuda()
```

works like magic for me.

BTW, according [the doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html): *input_var can be on any device, including CPU*

Comment: As soon as I run this, it drops something in the memory of GPU 0 even if I do not have the GPU 0 in my list. I can see it in `nvidia-smi`, done with a before-and-after check. I would like to run everything on 4,5,6,7. How do I write the command that it does not touch the GPU 0?

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the answers here does not help and if your training puts the parameters to another GPU than coded:

- It could be an unwanted default for GPU 2 that you cannot change easily, I had this with the Transformers Trainer class that saves the parameters always on GPU 0, see [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters ... on device cuda:6 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556).
- It could be a mapping problem so that "`cuda:1`" is mapped to GPU 2. I had this with all other GPUs. The only one that stayed the same was `'cuda:0'` which was mapped to GPU 0. I do not think that this is by chance. I guess that there was some setting at the launch of the server that chose this order of GPUs. For more on this, see ["model.to('cuda:6')" becomes (nvidia-smi) GPU 4, same with any other "cuda:MY_GPU", only "cuda:0" becomes GPU 0. How do I get rid of this mapping?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126490/97556). In short: check a few `model.to('cuda:3')`, `model.to('cuda:4')` and see after each step in `nvidia-smi` whether they are mapped to another GPU. If so, you need to make find the mapping of GPU 2 (could be `'cuda:6'` or the like) and code with that as a replacement of `'cuda:2'`.

Answer (score -1):

For me even the following works:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    network = nn.DataParallel(network)

network.to(device)
tnsr = tnsr.to(device)
```

Comment: This works because `device='cuda'` is synonymous with `device='cuda:0'` which is the default primary device for `DataParallel`.