# DistributedDataParallel with gpu device ID specified in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu, distributed-training

I want to train my model through DistributedDataParallel on a single machine that has 8 GPUs. But I want to train my model on four specified GPUs with device IDs 4, 5, 6, 7.

How to specify the GPU device ID for DistributedDataParallel?

I think the world size will be 4 for this case, but what should be the rank in this case?

Comment: And for those who wonder how you can know which GPUs are best choice, you need to run `nvidia-smi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. Torch will read this variable and only use the GPUs specified in there.
You can either do this directly in your python code like this:

```py
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '4, 5, 6, 7'
```

Take care to execute this command before you initialize torch in any way, else the statement will not take effect.
The other option would be to set the environment variable temporarily before starting your script in the shell:

```sh
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7 python your_script.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not, please let me know why so it can be improved

Comment: could you check this question please? ty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74380417/how-to-use-multiple-gpu-at-the-same-time-when-using-models-with-pytorch-and-hugg

Comment: This does not work for me. I have two GPUs with their memory almost full, six other GPUs show 0 memory. My code runs with `DataParallel` and not with `DistributedDataParallel`, but that should be the same. When I `!kill -9 123456` the pid that I find with `!nvidia-smi` and restart the kernel, I check the environment variable with `%env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, and the list is as is should be, without two of the GPUs that are quite high in memory already. But running the code, it still runs also on those two GPUs and crashes with the same bottleneck of 100 % memory.

Comment: @questionto42, DataParallel allows you to directly specify the device_ids upon instatiation, like this: `parallel_net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[2,3,4])`, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html). Make sure you move your model to a correct GPU beforehand too.

Comment: I code with the PyTorch Trainer class, see [Train with PyTorch Trainer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#train-with-pytorch-trainer). The only thing I have is the model object. I can also run `torch.nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[2,3,4])`, I get an output from that, but the memory still crashes in the bottleneck GPUs. Could it be that I have to restart the Jupyter Notebook server, not just the kernel?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with HuggingFace Pytorch Trainer. But nevertheless, it seems like you move something onto the bottleneck GPUs at some point in your training.

Comment: (btw, you forgot the ping) I found it out, you can just overwrite the DataParellel model with the given model. Therefore, the trainer class can easily grab this. Yet, I found no way up to now to avoid two of the 8 GPUs. I made a few remarks at [RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255526/11154841). I guess this is just a problem of user rights.

Comment: I found out how I can avoid devices. There is a strange mapping in my server setup. See ["model.to('cuda:6')" becomes (nvidia-smi) GPU 4, same with any other "cuda:MY_GPU", only "cuda:0" becomes GPU 0. How do I get rid of this mapping?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126490/97556). And for more on `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, see [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters ... on device cuda:6 (device_ids\[0\]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556). `os.environ[]` does not work, only `export`/CLI works.

Comment: I also found out that I cannot set the environment variable with `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '4, 5, 6, 7'`. It has to be set with `!export ...` while Python code will even override and disturb an elsewise working CLI-set environment variable. See the code proof at Stack Overflow [How to Solve "CUDA: Invalid Device Ordinal" Error in PyTorch Single-GPU Inference on a Model Trained with DataParallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856985/11154841).

Comment: @questionto42, seems like your issue is very specific to code run in jupyter notebooks, not sure how relevant it is if you do not use jupyter.

Comment: It is the same problem if you run a python file from CLI. It is therefore not a problem of Jupyter Notebook. You see this by the last link above (How to solve ...). That is about the same problem, but the code is run with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python forward_test_ins.py` from CLI. It is quite likely the same problem of `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']` inside the Python file, though I have not tested it.