# How to solve "CUDA: Invalid Device Ordinal" Error in PyTorch Single-GPU Inference on a Model Trained with DataParallel

Tags: python, pytorch

I encountered a

```
   CUDA: invalid device ordinal
```

error when doing single-GPU inference on a model trained with PyTorch's DataParallel module. The error disappears when I set the batch size to 1.
For batch size large than 1, I have used

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python forward_test_ins.py
```

But the problem still exists.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to give more details. What is the code that is causing the error? What batch size are you talking about? You haven't provided nearly enough detail to say for sure what is going on, other than a general description of what the error represents: you've tried to use a GPU with an ID/index outside of what exists on your machine.

Comment: This happens if you run the code on a device that is not there. But that is odd since `0` is the PyTorch default primary device `"cuda:0"`. It should always be there. You might check whether you have GPUs at all with `print(torch.cuda.device_count())`.

Comment: I ran into this the other day. Double check the properties file for the model you are trying to train. See if there is a setting that is just `device: n` where `n` is some integer. If `n` is not zero, change it to zero.

Answer (score -1):

##### TLDR

I prove with this answer that one of the ways to get this error is if the Python code inside the file sets the environment variable which overrides the elsewise working CLI-set environment variable at the beginning. There is working code as a proof.

##### Code that throws this error

The error "RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal" is thrown with the following code in a Jupyter Notebook cell:

```py
!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'

import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '4,5,6,7'

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_name = "dbmdz/german-gpt2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
config = model.config

# model.to('cuda:4')
# # RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
# model.to('cuda:5')
# # RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
# model.to('cuda:6')
# # RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
# model.to('cuda:7')
# # RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal

# While instead, and astonishingly, all other devices 0-3 work:
model.to('cuda:0')
# works
model.to('cuda:1')
# works
model.to('cuda:2')
# works
model.to('cuda:3')
# works
```

Here is the long error traceback if the model is put on one of the `os.environ[]` devices:

```py
model.to('cuda:5')
```

Out:

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [11], line 1
----> 1 model.to('cuda:5')

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1145, in Module.to(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1141         return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1142                     non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
   1143     return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
-> 1145 return self._apply(convert)

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:797, in Module._apply(self, fn)
    795 def _apply(self, fn):
    796     for module in self.children():
--> 797         module._apply(fn)
    799     def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    800         if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
    801             # If the new tensor has compatible tensor type as the existing tensor,
    802             # the current behavior is to change the tensor in-place using `.data =`,
   (...)
    807             # global flag to let the user control whether they want the future
    808             # behavior of overwriting the existing tensor or not.

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:797, in Module._apply(self, fn)
    795 def _apply(self, fn):
    796     for module in self.children():
--> 797         module._apply(fn)
    799     def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    800         if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
    801             # If the new tensor has compatible tensor type as the existing tensor,
    802             # the current behavior is to change the tensor in-place using `.data =`,
   (...)
    807             # global flag to let the user control whether they want the future
    808             # behavior of overwriting the existing tensor or not.

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:820, in Module._apply(self, fn)
    816 # Tensors stored in modules are graph leaves, and we don't want to
    817 # track autograd history of `param_applied`, so we have to use
    818 # `with torch.no_grad():`
    819 with torch.no_grad():
--> 820     param_applied = fn(param)
    821 should_use_set_data = compute_should_use_set_data(param, param_applied)
    822 if should_use_set_data:

File /srv/home/seid/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1143, in Module.to.<locals>.convert(t)
   1140 if convert_to_format is not None and t.dim() in (4, 5):
   1141     return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1142                 non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
-> 1143 return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

And here is how it looks like for the working devices 0-3:

```py
model.to('cuda:2')
```

Out:

```bash
GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50265, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50265, bias=False)
)
```

I also checked it with:

```bash
%set_env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'
```

This code throws the same error:

```py
!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'
%set_env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_name = "dbmdz/german-gpt2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
config = model.config

model.to('cuda:4')
```

Thus, do not write `%set_env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'` since it is the same as the failing `os.environ[]`. If you write that after the `!export ...` line and drop the `os.envion[]`, you get the same error in the output.

Funny enough, there was not hint at `!export ...` among *all* of the answers at [How to set env variable in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37890898/11154841) - and that is a gold question:

- Asked 7 years, 7 months ago
- Viewed 337k times
- 212 upvotes
- 12 answers, the highest 274 which says that you can take `%set_env`

##### Answer

The example is for devices 4,5,6,7. Check whether you have `os.environ[]` or `%set_env` in the Python code.

If you begin with:

```py
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '4,5,6,7'
```

Instead of the right:

```bash
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'
```

Or if you are in a Jupyter Notebook cell:

```bash
!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'
```

Or:

```bash
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7 python forward_test_ins.py
# and then without os.environ in the forward_test_ins.py!
```

##### Answer

You must drop `os.environ[]` from the Python file since that overwrites the CLI command. Thus, even if you run your Python executable with the right setting, it is overridden by the `os.environ[]` - which does not work since it is not on CLI level.

Links:

- [os.environ[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES] does not work well](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/os-environ-cuda-visible-devices-does-not-work-well/132461) :

> it shouldn’t be inside the python script but to be set as an enviroment variable in the console such as CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python your_script.py Note that you SHOUDLN’T t set it as a permanent enviroment variable in the bashrc as it affects the whole system.

- [How to set env variable in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857149/11154841), and the [os.environ[] answer of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994999/11154841) does not say that it might be the wrong choice.

##### Code answer

This runs through if you `!export ...` at the beginning of the cell.
You can also run your Python executable with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=4,5,6,7 python forward_test_ins.py` and leave that code line `!export ...` out.

```py
!export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7'

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

model_name = "dbmdz/german-gpt2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
config = model.config

model.to('cuda:4')
```

You can also set environment variables in the .bashrc, see [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326270/11154841), or the Jupyter Notebook service settings, see [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43217327/11154841) (but mind: the error will also be thrown outside of Jupyter Notebook, thus, better change the .bashrc (link 1) and not the Jupyter Notebook service settings (link 2).

##### ParallelData

If you get the error only from code with ParallelData, mind that ParallelData will always save the parameters and buffers to GPU 0, see [Transformers Trainer: "RuntimeError: module must have its parameters ... on device cuda:6 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:0"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126493/97556), therefore, in the example above, better take a `device_ids` list that begins with `0` and also put that at the beginning of `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. In your question, you show a snippet with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0`, therefore, this code cannot run into an error like that. But if you ran `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` instead, you will get problems with two devices, 0 and 1, that both save parameters and buffers even though only one device is allowed to do that.

##### Other device problems if you work with many GPUs

What also (perhaps-perhaps) might disturb your devices is a strange mapping, namely that a coded GPU becomes another GPU that is being worked on. Check this with the CLI command `nvidia-smi` (Jupyter Notebook: `!nvidia-smi`). See ["model.to('cuda:6')" becomes (nvidia-smi) GPU 4, same with any other "cuda:MY_GPU", only "cuda:0" becomes GPU 0. How do I get rid of this mapping?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126490/97556). Since I have this strange mapping in my setup and since I got the same error in question with `os.environ[]`, you might check that. For example, to get 0,4,5,6,7, I had to code: 0,6,3,7,2. UPDATE: There is an answer to that strange mapping question. And the link is a cross-site duplicate of [How does CUDA assign device IDs to GPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13781738/11154841).

Comment: Torch will always number the visible devices starting from zero. So even if you use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='4,5,6,7', you will only be able to use cuda:0 to cuda:3.

Comment: It is also relevant that you set the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES before importing torch. Then there is no difference between exporting it in your terminal or setting it in python using os.

Comment: @besterma I do not import torch anywhere in the code, that is done indirectly perhaps by the Trainer class. But if you set the environment variable with `os.environ[]`, it will not work even if it is done before torch. Setting it with Python code just does not work at all, at least in my tests in Jupyter Notebook. And from the question example we can guess that it is the same for a python file that is run from command line (untested, but likely): as soon as you have the `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']` in the Python file, you get the error in question (again: untested, but likely).